# Combine time(Object type) and Date(Datetime64[ns])

Tags: python, pandas

My data set contains multiple columns of sales-related data. I have `ORDEREDDATE` and `TIMESTAMP` in the DataFrame. I want to replace the column with  `ORDEREDTIME` in the dataset.

```
ORDEREDDATE  TIMESTAMP
 2018-05-13   21:54:45   
 2017-08-24   5:44:25      
 2018-06-01   6:58:15
```

my expected output is

```
          ORDEREDTIME
     2018-05-13 21:54:45   
     2017-08-24 05:44:25      
     2018-06-01 06:58:15
```

in a single column.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: I did try some but not at all useful. Posting those here confuses people. That's the reason I have posted the details of the problem. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['ORDEREDDATE','TIMESTAMP']].astype(str).agg(' '.join,1))
Out[19]: 
0   2018-05-13 21:54:45
1   2017-08-24 05:44:25
2   2018-06-01 06:58:15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
df['ORDEREDTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df.astype(str).agg(' '.join,1))
```

Comment: The df contains a lot of columns other than this. Can you please be more specific in the code.